# iptables MSS clamping confusion

Tags: iptables

I have a Raspberry PI (Raspbian), which I'm using as a gateway for my home internet. It just uses a set of iptables rules.

Everything is working fine with this, except for one very specific issue using the YouTube app on my Sky Q box. Nothing would load and it stuck on "Loading..." Everywhere else (mobiles, tablets, browsers) YouTube would load just fine.

Now after some [Googling](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html) about this issue, I found that adding this line should fix the problem.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

And lo and behold, it did indeed fix it.

The thing is I already had this rule in my iptables script:

```
iptables -t mangle -o ppp0 --insert FORWARD 1 -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1400:65495 -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

My question is what is the difference? I'm not understanding why the FORWARD rule was necessary and how it differs from what I already had?